# ZedGraph Bar Width

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is there a way to modify the width of a ZedGraph bar?  If so, what is the code necessary to do so?  Is it possible to make it so the bars scale with the zoom also?  I have bars that don't show up because of the way the scaling works currently (there is a wide x-axis range, which makes all of the bars very skinny).  If the bar is too narrow, it won't show up at all.  I'd like the bars to be wider so they will always show up without having to zoom in to see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx) has the following to say about bar type graphs (emphasis mine):

> Typically, bar charts would be created with `XAxis.Type = AxisType.Text` or `XAxis.Type = AxisType.Ordinal` (both types use ordinal values), such that the bars are drawn at integral values along the "base" axis, starting with 1 (e.g., the first bar cluster is at 1.0, the second is at 2.0, etc.). However, the ordinal axis type is not a requirement for bar charts. **It is possible to create a bar chart that is not evenly spaced, by providing X values and using `AxisType.Linear` (in this case, you may need to use the `GraphPane.ClusterScaleWidth` property to tell ZedGraph how wide the bars should be. See this wiki page for details).** For bar charts, the tic marks are typically between the bar clusters, which can be accomplished with the `Axis.MajorTic.IsBetweenLabels` property. However, this property is only applicable for `AxisType.Text` axes.

Unfortunately the wiki link goes to the old domain which the authors of ZedGraph seem to have abandoned. However there is an archived version: [Wiki Page](http://web.archive.org/web/20101225021851/http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_is_BarItem_affected_by_AxisType%3F)

Finally you may find it helpful to check the excellent [source code reference at sourceforge](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/default.html).